# cat specific columns in 3 files

Tags: awk, sed, cat, xargs

I have 3 files such as :

file1_file:

```
scaffold_159    625 YP_009345712    0.284   447 289 9   96675   95377   196 625 6.963E-38   158
scaffold_159    625 YP_009345714    0.284   447 289 9   96675   95377   196 625 6.963E-38   158
IDBA_scaffold_24562 625 YP_009345713    0.464   56  20  2   2549    2686    10  65  7.513E-03   37
```

file2_file:

```
scaffold_159    625 YP_009345717    0.284   447 289 9   96675   95377   196 625 6.963E-38   158
scaffold_159    625 YP_009345718    0.284   447 289 9   96675   95377   196 625 6.963E-38   158
IDBA_scaffold_24562 625 YP_009345719    0.464   56  20  2   2549    2686    10  65  7.513E-03   37
```

file3_file:

```
scaffold_159    625 YP_009345711    0.284   447 289 9   96675   95377   196 625 6.963E-38   158
scaffold_159    625 YP_009345723    0.284   447 289 9   96675   95377   196 625 6.963E-38   158
IDBA_scaffold_24562 625 YP_009345721    0.464   56  20  2   2549    2686    10  65  7.513E-03   37
```

and I would like to only get the 3th part of the 3 file in a single `new_file.txt`.

Here I should get :

```
YP_009345712
YP_009345714
YP_009345713
YP_009345717
YP_009345718
YP_009345711
YP_009345723
YP_009345721
```

From now I tried:

```
cat file_names.txt | while read line; do cat /path1/${line}/path2/${line}_file > new_file.txt; done
```

in `file_names.txt`  I have :

```
file1
file2
file3
```

but I do not know how to extract only the 3th column...

Ps: the 3 files are not in the same directory :

```
/path1/file1/path2/file1_file 
/path1/file2/path2/file2_file 
/path1/file3/path2/file3_file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** After chatting with OP came to know that his/her files could be on different locations, so in that case could you please try following. Considering that you have an Input_file where all file names are there. I am yet to test it.

```
file_name=$(awk '{val=(val?val OFS:"")"/path1/" $0 "/path2/" $0} END{print val}' file_names.txt)
awk '{print $3}' "$file_name"
```

***OR***

```
awk '{print $3}' $(awk '{val=(val?val OFS:"")"/path1/" $0 "/path2/" $0} END{print val}' file_names.txt)
```

---

---

You could use `awk` here.

```
awk '{print $3}' /complete_path/file1 /complete_path/file2  /complete_path/file3
```

Comment: @chippycentra, Please check my EDIT solutions and lemme know in case of any queries here.

Answer (score 1):

I think it can be simpler with

```
$ sed 's_.*_"path1/&/path2/&"_' filenames | xargs awk '{print $3}'
```

`awk` will be called only once.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a file `fnames.txt` with hundreds of strings:

```
str1
str2
str3
str4
...
```

and each string represents a file located in

```
/path1/${str}/path2/${str}_file
```

where `${str}` is a value from file `fnames.txt`.

Now you want to read the third column, from the third file only:

```
$ str="$(awk '(NR==3){print; exit}' fnames.txt)"
$ file="/path1/${str}/path2/${str}_file"
$ awk '{print $3}' "$file" > new_file.txt
```

Always remember the [KISS principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)